# Extracting data for stats

Tags: python, django

I have these two models:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    ...
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alpha_2_code = models.CharField("Alpha-2 code", max_length=2, unique=True)
    alpha_3_code = models.CharField("Alpha-3 code", max_length=3, unique=True)
    numeric_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Numeric code", max_length=3, unique=True)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(max_length=3)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I am trying to do is having Google Map Chart displayed based on the log entries, so what I should pass to the templates is something like this:

```
    function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Popularity'],
            ['Germany', 200],
            ['United States', 300],
            ['Brazil', 400],
            ['Canada', 500],
            ['France', 600],
            ['RU', 700]
        ]);
```

What is the fastest way to extract and pass the data to templates?

Comment: what is popularity?  i also edited the code - you had Country being defined inside Log.

Comment: same question, popularity is the key to answer this question

Comment: @Adam - Irrelevant to your required answer .. i would like to ask you that .. Dont you think `Class Log` should have `user` as `OnetoOneField` instead `ForeignKey` to `auth.User` .. (if one user can belong to one country only that - should be actually ) ?? Because that can effect the answer below alot for your stats ..

Comment: @ManujRastogi Actually the user my have many "Log".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that `popularity` is defined as the SQL `count` of the `Log` model, grouped by country. Correct me if I'm wrong. See the [aggregation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) for more information.

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = Log.objects.values('country__name').annotate(popularity=Count('country__name'))
```

Then in your template you'd do:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Popularity'],
        {% for log in queryset %}
        ['{{ log.country.name }}', {{ log.popularity }} ] {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]);
```

Note that in the template I'm checking the forloop for the last iteration, and not including a trailing comma if it is the last iteration.

Comment: Depending on the OP needs and what Log records, I suspect we should normalize popularity for country population size, and perhaps account for differences in broadband internet penetration. :-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling, it might have helped if he'd defined what the numbers meant :P But I think my example should get OP most of the way there.